# Saving order PDF when order is placed?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

**Magento 1.9.3.2**

I am trying to save the order PDF right after an order is placed / saved. The event I am using is `sales_order_place_after`. This is working fine, except for the payment information. That is not printed on the PDF whenever an external payment was made using PayPal+ or eBay.

> This is the `Observer.php` code:

```
$pdf = Mage::getModel('emailattachments/order_pdf_order')->getPdf(array($order));
$pdf->render();
$pdf->save("my.pdf");
```

**I guess the payment data is not available at this point in the event chain? Is there another event maybe that I can use? I checked, it does not seem so.**

> Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We are using the event `sales_order_invoice_pay` to generate a order PDF. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25071094/6221202) on that event. When that event is dispatched payment information should be available.

Comment: This is not always fired when the order is placed I guess, or is it? I need to create the PDF in the order creation process, no matter if it comes from eBay or the Magento shop. Would that work with that event?

Comment: Not immediately I think. It is fired when the payment is complete i.e. when the order transitions from "Pending Payment" to "Complete". Depending on the payment method (e.g. PayPal) this could take some time.